# Is this person doing illegal money transfers?

Tags: scams, fraud, money-laundering

This girl that I'm friends with and have actually seen in person before, keeps posting [on social media] that she "loves when the transfer goes through" and gets $2000-$6000 for free quite often. She said you can make up to $6500 a day. She is not very smart and barely spells correctly. She keeps saying that all she is doing is "transfers" and that's it. So many of my friends are feeding into this crap. So I asked her what it is. She basically said "it's legit" and asked me for my bank username and password so she could see how much money to deposit into my account. I said no way and left it at that. She also said she is not stealing or doing anything illegal. She is getting her friends free money and I think they're naive. What is she actually doing? Is it illegal? I am sure she is incapable of doing crazy money wiring to different countries.

Thank you everyone for answering my question. I am not stupid, I did not give her my information. I knew she was up to something illegal, so thank you for giving me some input on what exactly she is doing. I submitted an anonymous tip to my local sheriff's department. I'm hoping they see it and pursue it, or forward it to the right authorities I.e the FBI or something.

Comment: Tl;dr: This is not a friend. Run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this money transfer a legal way to get money?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49056/is-this-money-transfer-a-legal-way-to-get-money)

Comment: "asked me for my bank username and password"... yeah, sounds legit...

Comment: There's an old saying among bankers and ear doctors: If something sounds too good to be true, it isn't true.

Comment: @Philipp, I think this is different from the one you listed

Comment: I think FinCEN would be very interested to speak to your friend..

Comment: This is 100 percent a scam as explained by multiple other posters, *but it does open a way to make money.* Reward money posted by law enforcement and victimized banks. I suggest you try to collect, making an appointment with the relevant authorities.

Comment: She's not my FRIEND. We are just friends on Facebook. She used to hang with my fiance's little sister and is now hated by many. I didn't fall for her little trick. I was wondering what exactly she was doing so I could know if I should go to the police or not.

Comment: You should actually probably block and report her to Facebook. Block to deny her access to your friends list, and report to protect others.

Comment: Did you ask her for her bank account info and password so you can see how much money she is making for herself? I mean... you need verification of her success and what not... right?

Comment: She posted a video of her counting hundreds. She really has the money, and her friends have posted selfies holding hundred dollar bills. They are very stupid. Bragging about illegal money scams. LOL.

Comment: I wish I could attach the pictures to show you. It is insane.

Comment: @AutumnThompson It's pretty common to show off like that with fake money, or with a couple real $100s and then a bunch of ones underneath. Easy to do, especially on a video where you can't look more closely.

Comment: apply the old money-making razor, and you will see that it is not legal: TINSTAAFL

Comment: You might as well tattoo "Criminal" on her forehead... This has "Money Laundering" written all over it. There is **no way** that is "legit" or "legal".

Comment: @AutumnThompson Are you sure she is not the victim? I'm asking because you haven't hesitated to let us know how stupid she is :D

Comment: `she "loves when the transfer goes through"`, `She is not very smart`, `barely spells correctly`, `keeps saying that all she is doing is "transfers"`, `She also said she is not stealing or doing anything illegal.`, `she is incapable of doing crazy money wiring to different countries.`, `said "it's legit" and asked me for my bank username and password`. Somebody who brags about doing something that is almost definitely illegal (not to forget, she **can't** spell), doesn't sound like a "criminal" I feel like she has been tricked into thinking that what she is doing is all-right, legit and legal.

Comment: "She posted a video of her counting hundreds." -- I just got paid today. I could post a video of me counting hundreds of dollars. It doesn't prove I make that money every day! It could also be fake money (look up 50 Cent, the rapper, and see his fake millions he posted pictures of online). -- I once got a personal loan to buy a relatively expensive item, and the bank gave me cash. I was a lot younger then, but I did pose for pictures with thousands of dollars thrown on the ground and me laying in it. Was funny at the time... just stupid in hindsight.

Comment: Yea maybe she isn't aware that what she is doing is illegal or has fallen prey to a much larger scam.

Comment: Okay, so she slept with some Colombian "tourist" who left his wallet in her car. She got some banking info and found hundreds of millions flowing in/out of the account. She decided to share. Seriously, how could that cause trouble? Colombians are very friendly. Surely they won't want it back.

Comment: sounds like a money mule to me

Comment: @user2338816 Just called the airport, they allowed to trade my ticket to LA with a one-way to Bogotá...

Comment: Yes, I agree with @SnakeDoc maybe she isn't making that money everyday...

Comment: It's also possible that the social media account in question is a spoof of the account of the person you've actually met and isn't actually owned by her. This is somewhat common. However, if she's posting pictures/videos of herself with the money with this account, that's probably not the case.

Comment: http://www.wired.com/2015/10/online-dating-made-woman-pawn-global-crime-plot/

Comment: Why don't you just report this person already?

Comment: @djechlin: This is not a friend in any sense but the social media redefinition of that word. Heck, if it wasn't for the video we wouldn't even know she was female, and even then there's room for doubt; if this is an organized operation (as it probably is, these days) they may be using one vid to represent multiple identities... But we've gotta call the perp _something_ for discussion purposes, and she presented herself as a gal, so...

Comment: They send money from a hacked account into a mule account. The mule then withdraws it, and sends it to the hacker/fraudster.

Comment: The apparent stupidity and misspellings may be an act also, to feel more authentic to her target audience (more unquestioning money mules) and to weed out people with good sense. The photos of new recruits may be staged (possibly blackmailed).

Comment: "She is not very smart" + _she knows what she is doing_ + you don't know "What is she actually doing?" --> when you don't know who the mark is at a poker game, time to leave.

Comment: @Mango Or a scammer pretending to be stupid to make sure only stupid people fall.

Answer (score 173):

She is laundering money for criminals, either knowingly or unknowingly.

There are lots of ways to make a fraudulent money transfer from an account one does not own. Stolen credit card numbers, direct debit fraud, phished PayPal logins or online banking trojans are some examples.

Unfortunately (for the criminals) when a customer informs their bank that someone made a transfer from their account they did not authorize, then the bank will usually reverse that transfer and inform the authorities. So criminals can not directly wire these transfers into their personal accounts. The stolen money would disappear and they would get caught.

That's where so-called "mules" come in. Mules are people who are hired by criminals to receive such dirty money and move it to a different account controlled by the criminals. When the transfer gets reversed, two things happen:

1. The transfer from victim to mule gets reversed, but not the transfer from mule to criminal, so the mule loses their money while the criminal keeps theirs. That means the person who is the actual victim in the scheme is the mule.
2. Law enforcement gets suspicious of the mule and might knock on their door.

Your "friend" is either one of these mules or is in the business of recruiting mules.

Comment: So why doesn't the bank ever reverse the mule->criminal transaction?

Comment: @immibis in many (most?) cases the mule doesn't perform the transfer using a bank but rather some other method (mail, western union). This is particularly often done using checks which bounce. I.e. someone sends you a 1k check and says he just wants you to send 200 back to him after you deposit it. You deposit it get 1k and send 200 back when the check bounces you're 200 down.

Comment: @immibis If you (mule) are using your real account with real credentials and deliberately authorizing the transfer (to criminal) then there is no unauthorized transaction to reverse. From the bank's perspective they only reverse *unauthorized transactions*; you (mule) explicitly authorized and approved the transaction, which gives relatively little recourse under both T&Cs and laws in most scenarios.

Comment: Presumably if you (mule) want to report the criminal has having defrauded you, for example if you say that the transfer was in return for money that wasn't delivered because it got reversed, then in principle the mule->criminal transfer could be reversed too. But in practice, saying "my accomplice didn't hold up their end of our joint criminal enterprise" doesn't count from the bank's POV as consumer fraud against you, and unlawful contracts/agreements generally can't be upheld anyway...

Comment: I don't think banks view frauds that they weren't a party to as their problem generally. The fraud is committed by the criminal in this case and the victim is the mule. The banks are acting in good faith on your instructions. In the UK best case if you made the outbound transfer via credit card somehow (cheque if anyone has that still?) I think you'd still have a hard time convincing them that S75 of the consumer credit act applied.

Comment: (Weirdly though if they're defrauded by a criminal into clearing out your account without any instruction or involvement from you they're more than happy to make up some claim of "identity fraud" that somehow makes it sound like your problem. Even though you're not a party to any actual fraud that's happened....)

Comment: Biggest clue it's a scam is she asked for other peoples bank usernames and passwords, to "see how much money to transfer". Not only does this not make sense, but to transfer money, you only need a routing number and account number. Gaining access to someone's online banking allows you to SEND money out of the account... So, it's possible this "friend" is logging into other "friend's" accounts and transferring their money.

Comment: I've +1ed your answer, but I think a "probably" or "likely" is warranted in your first sentence.

Comment: @immibis Criminals specifically use this method to adapt a reversible theft of funds to an irreversible withdrawal of the stolen funds. That's why they need someone with money to do it.

Answer (score 61):

> What is she actually doing? Is it illegal?

She is running some kind of scam and it is illegal. Quite often these are fronts. Generally people get suspicious if they haven't seen anyone. So you social engineer and someone like this girl would boost in her circle. The fact that she is making $6500 a day is unverified claim. I can say I make 1 million a day :)

There is no free money. It is wise of you not to share your Bank details. Stay away as far as possible.

Note depending on the country and regulation you could be in trouble with authorities for even knowing / suspecting that someone is committing fraud and not informing authorities.

Comment: "never attribute to malice that, which is adequately explained by stupidity" - but basically **+1** it's no possible way this is legit.

Comment: @s1lv3r: yeah, you can on that principle reserve judgement as to whether she understands what she's doing, but *somebody* involved in this scheme understands it. No way are some people shuffling money around in a way that leaves her with some of it, and *everyone involved* is merely stupid.

Comment: She showed a video of her counting hundreds. So she really has the money. I want to report her to the police but that's a lot of stress on me. I don't want them to keep bugging me I just want to report her so they can pursue it.

Comment: @AutumnThompson Without ANY kind of scam... lemme pass by my bank, empty my account, and you'll have videos of me counting 1K bills instead of hundreds. Doesn't mean I acquired that money the way I say I have... just means I have the money.

Comment: @Patrice: It even just means you have the cash. Doesn't have to mean you actually own that money. Get a loan, cash it out, count the bills on camera, pay it back before interest builds up. :-P

Comment: @das-g even better point than mine!

Comment: A video of counting hundreds means that at that one moment she was holding hundreds.  Not that this is how she got them, or that they were hers, or even that they were real money. If anything, this sort of stunt is evidence against the scheme.

Comment: @keshlam If you have no money but access to a high quality color printer, you could just print out lots and lots of fake money, make your video, and destroy the counterfeits before the Secret Service pays a call.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be counterfeit; stage money would be more than sufficient for most of the bills, since the viewer can't inspect them.

Comment: @s1lv3r yeah, it doesn't have to be HER that does the (knowingly) illegal stuff (and guessing by how open she is about it its 100% stupidity on her part, not malice. But SOMEONE is moving fat racks around here, and given HOW theyre moved they were not aquired legally

Answer (score 41):

She **claimed** that she makes money. When you wanted to make some too, she asked for your account credentials - which are only needed to take money away, never to give.

The simplest explanation would be loan scam: Even if you have only $10 on your account, you can lose much more - the trick is that someone using your credentials can take an online loan in your name, and steal that money. If the scheme is long-running, she'll be taking new loans and using the money to pay back the earlier ones, building up credit history for her victims - only to allow taking even bigger loans. Her victims see the incoming transfers and are happy about the scheme "working". Until she decides that the pot is big enough to cash it in and disappear, leaving everyone deep in debt.

Those who fell for this could be already defaulting loans they have no idea about and the loan companies have no way of notifying them, because she redirected the contact details.

**Never reveal your password.** Nobody needs your password for any legitimate purpose.

Comment: mint.com needs my password for a legitimate purpose. but i suppose that is arguably a "nobody"

Comment: @jamesturner Truthfully, I'd be careful about services like Mint. If they lose your password, there's nothing your bank can do for you.

Comment: Mint requests your *password*? I would be very, very uncomfortable giving a company access to my bank account like that. It's a pretty clear use case for a modular authorization scheme like OAuth.

Comment: @Paul: Somewhere around here there is an explanation of how Mint works, but basically they use a service that talks to the bank, and most of the banks don't talk OAuth (although I agree that they should, and have complained to my credit union that they don't). So, in a sense it isn't their fault, but is even worse than you thought...

Comment: Yeah, many banks hold the transaction history as hostage, and fail to provide sane ways to get it for analysis by 3rd party services. Pretty many services end up using the password-based workaround, but indeed it is pretty insecure.

Comment: @jamesturner If it can log in and parse the HTML, it's capabable of accepting you copy-pasting the part you want to share. Giving away your bank password is like painting room with explosives - sometimes it may work, but there are sane ways of doing it.

Comment: @Agent_L the advantage of mint is that i don't have to manually copy and paste my data every time i want a consolidated view. if i wanted to do that, i would go back to using a spreadsheet.

Comment: i don't beleive any banks support oauth. there are a few financial institutions (e.g. tradeking i believe) that have a separate read-only password for external api access.

Comment: @jamesturner Of course. There is always convenience vs security issue. You can give me your bank credentials and I'll manage all your finances, don't you worry about that : )

Comment: @Agent_L obviously mint is much more convenient, but i don't see a significant security risk in using the service.  in fact, using a read-only view like mint for day-to-day access reduces the damage that could be done if someone captures my password using a keylogger or shoulder surfing, etc.

Comment: @jamesturner Whenever somebody else have your full credentials and is able to impersonate you - it constitutes HUGE security risk on its own. We grew used to believe that Mint won't clean up all client accounts one day - but it's nothing but a promise. If Mint falls into wrong hands - there will be nothing stopping them (except for 3-factor authorization, like single-use codes texted to your phone). Agree about the second part - you're exchanging trust. If your computer is less trusted than Mint, then yes, it does increase security. **If**.

Answer (score 19):

This will end badly, the only question is how long it will take.

Performing bank transfers is not difficult and there is no way a 3rd party would be paying her large sums of money to perform these transfers unless the purpose was illegitimate and they were taking advantage of her.

In my experience it is as simple as entering the target bank account routing and account #, entering the name (this is not double-checked by the bank to associate with the target account), entering a dollar amount and then agreeing to the terms of the transfer--there are not people out there who have a lot of money but would rather pay somebody $2000+ to do 2 minutes of work in an unofficial capacity instead of just doing it themselves unless they are trying to hide something and/or take advantage of a *mark*.

Comment: Doing the transfer is likely less effort than emailing her to tell her to do it. Nobody pays clean money for work that doesn't need to be done.

Answer (score 10):

They will pay, that's for sure.
It's something common in many countries.
Sometimes it is stolen money like Philipp said.
Sometimes is money from mafia or terrorist groups that needs to be transferred so they use naive people whose profile wouldn't be suspicious if they get sums of money. They will look your past transactions to determine the amount of money they could transfer to you without alerting someone. Why?

Because lets say you are a criminal. If you sell 10 kilos of cocaine, some bombs or girls for prostitution and receive the money lets say one million dollars in just one deposit in one bank account, someone will be knocking at your door very soon, it will be easy to prove the illegal source of the founds and you get nothing.

If you have 25 guys working for you and they receive transfers and deposits of less amount frequently, from let's say 150 different accounts belonging to account holders with no criminal record. It is harder to be noticed and you could say they are legal activities (15000 a month received from entrepreneurs or 2500 from a housewife is not too much). It will be harder to prove that all the transactions come from illegal money and by the time it is proven usually the money has already gone somewhere else (by using another network of mules like your friend's).

I don't know the laws where you are, but this is illegal in many countries. If you enter they won't let you out of the network, and when something goes wrong you will need to explain a lot.

Comment: Crime is illegal in pretty any country, that has any kind of law other than the law of the strongest ;)